# Get distinct value and its count in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel column **Vehicle type** where vehicles are inserted repeatedly. In new sheet of excel I want to display (using excel formula) vehicle in one column and number of times it was repeated on next column and next row next vehicle and it number of existence. **MS Excel 2007**
[image]

Comment: Which version of Excel? A pivot table would be the simplest method rather than formulas, for most versions.

Comment: But I want formula.

Comment: Excel 2007 Version. I don't want to update, I just want solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft Excel 365 then use below formulas.

```
E2=UNIQUE(A2:A16)
F2=COUNTIF(A2:A16,E3#)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest version of excel then

To find unique values, use =UNIQUE(A1:A20)

To find the count, use =COUNTIF(A1:A20,C1)

[image]

Comment: I am using excel 2007. I don't want to update it, I just want solution according to it.